# DirectX 12 doesn't draw triangle

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, directx-12

I'm learning DirectX 12. I would like to draw a triangle, but DirectX 12 doesn't draw it. I wonder if there's something I forgot.

This is Init() part.

```cpp
void Engine::Init() {
    mDevice = new Device();
    mCommandQueue = new CommandQueue();
    mSwapChain = new SwapChain();
    mDescriptorHeap = new DescriptorHeap();
    mRootSignature = new RootSignature();

    mDevice->Init();
    mCommandQueue->Init(mDevice->GetDevice());
    mSwapChain->Init(mDevice->GetDevice(), mDevice->GetFactory(), mCommandQueue->GetCommandQueue(), mWndInfo);
    mDescriptorHeap->Init(mDevice->GetDevice(), mSwapChain);
    mRootSignature->Init(mDevice->GetDevice());

    mesh = new Mesh();
    shader = new Shader(mRootSignature);

    D3D12_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC desc[] = {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };

    shader->Init(mDevice->GetDevice(), L"..\\Resources\\Shader\\default.hlsli");
    shader->SetPipelineState(mDevice->GetDevice(), desc, _countof(desc));

    std::vector<Vertex> vec(3);
    vec[0].pos = Vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    vec[0].color = Vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    vec[1].pos = Vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    vec[1].color = Vec4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    vec[2].pos = Vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    vec[2].color = Vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    mesh->Init(mDevice->GetDevice(), vec);

    mCommandQueue->WaitForPreviousFrame(mSwapChain);
}
```

```cpp
void Mesh::Init(ID3D12Device* const device, const std::vector<Vertex>& vec) {
    mVertexCount = static_cast<uint32>(vec.size());
    const uint32 bufferSize = mVertexCount * sizeof(Vertex);
    
    D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES heapProperties = CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD);
    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC resourceDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(bufferSize);

    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &heapProperties,
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &resourceDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&mVertexBuffer)));

    // Copy the triangle data to the vertex buffer.
    void* pVertexDataBuffer = nullptr;
    CD3DX12_RANGE readRange(0, 0);        // We do not intend to read from this resource on the CPU.
    ThrowIfFailed(mVertexBuffer->Map(0, &readRange, &pVertexDataBuffer));
    std::memcpy(pVertexDataBuffer, &vec[0], bufferSize);
    mVertexBuffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);

    // Initialize the vertex buffer view.
    mVertexBufferView.BufferLocation = mVertexBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    mVertexBufferView.StrideInBytes = sizeof(Vertex);
    mVertexBufferView.SizeInBytes = bufferSize;
}
```

After Init, This code will be executed.

```cpp
void Engine::Render() {
    mCommandQueue->RenderBegin(mSwapChain, mDescriptorHeap, shader->GetGraphicsPSO(), &mViewport, &mScissorRect);
    
    mesh->Render(mCommandQueue->GetCommandList());

    mCommandQueue->RenderEnd(mSwapChain);
}
```

```cpp
void CommandQueue::RenderBegin(SwapChain* swapChain, DescriptorHeap* descHeap, GraphicsPSO* graphicsPSO, const D3D12_VIEWPORT* viewPort, const D3D12_RECT* scissorRect) {
    ThrowIfFailed(mCommandAllocator->Reset());
    ThrowIfFailed(mCommandList->Reset(mCommandAllocator, graphicsPSO->GetPipelineState()));

    mCommandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(graphicsPSO->GetRootSignatrue()->GetRootSignature());
    mCommandList->RSSetViewports(1, viewPort);
    mCommandList->RSSetScissorRects(1, scissorRect);


    // Indicate that the back buffer will be used as a render target.
    D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER resourceBarrierDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(swapChain->GetBackRtvBuffer(),
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET); 
    mCommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &resourceBarrierDesc);

    
    D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle = descHeap->GetBackRtvHandle(); 
    const float clearColor[] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
    mCommandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtvHandle, FALSE, nullptr);
    mCommandList->ClearRenderTargetView(rtvHandle, clearColor, 0, nullptr);
}
```

```cpp
void Mesh::Render(ID3D12GraphicsCommandList* cmdList) {
    cmdList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    cmdList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &mVertexBufferView);
    cmdList->DrawInstanced(mVertexCount, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

```cpp
void CommandQueue::RenderEnd(SwapChain* swapChain) {
    // Indicate that the back buffer will now be used to present.
    D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER resourceBarrierDesc = CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(swapChain->GetBackRtvBuffer(),
                                                        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET,
                                                        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT);

    mCommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &resourceBarrierDesc);
    ThrowIfFailed(mCommandList->Close());

    // Execute the command list.
    ID3D12CommandList* ppCommandLists[] = { mCommandList };
    mCommandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(_countof(ppCommandLists), ppCommandLists);

    // Back buffer <-> Front buffer
    swapChain->Present();
    WaitForPreviousFrame(swapChain);
    swapChain->SwapIndex();
}
```

Result is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tSsY.png)

There's no error. I compared my code with DirectX sample code "Hello Triangle", but I wrote most of DirectX code to render such as `OMSetRenderTargets`, `ResourceBarrier`, etc.

Windows 10, GTX 750ti, support DirectX 12.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I forgot to check the accept button. Thanks for reminding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cought the reason myself. It is because I got wrong with initialization of pipeline states.

```cpp
    ID3D12PipelineState* pipelineState = mGraphicsPSO->GetPipelineState();
    D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC desc = mGraphicsPSO->GetGraphicsPipelineStateDesc();
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&desc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pipelineState)));
```

this was my code where create graphics pipeline state. When I wrote this code, I had an error.

```cpp
ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&desc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mGraphicsPSO->GetPipelineState())));
```

I wanted to write like above. But it makes compile error, which is "C++ expression must be an lvalue or a function designator", because `mGraphicsPSO->GetPipelineState()`'s return is rvalue.

So, I thought that it might work if I wrote like the original code(the first code). UNFORTUNATELY it doesn't make compile error. It "works".

The problem of the first code is that the pipeline state pointer in class of GraphicsPSO is still `nullptr` because `ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&desc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pipelineState)));` this code will create graphics pipeline state to "pipelineState" which is not a member of class of GraphicsPSO.

And I wrote this question to StackOverflow.

Anyway, I suspected the first code and wrote test code:

```cpp
    D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC desc = mGraphicsPSO->GetGraphicsPipelineStateDesc();
    ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&desc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&mGraphicsPSO->mPipelineState)));
```

I moved mPipelineState from `protected` to `public` and wrote code like above. It works well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZGO3.png)

This is result.

I found the fundamental reason of the error but it doesn't mean that it is finished. I need to think how to fix my first code.